# How setup redis session timeout permanent on centos server

Tags: redis, session-timeout

I have a centos server. I installed redis on server.
I want to save a user to remain permanently logged in until a user clicks Logout function.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not explicitly set the timeout value for a key then the will never be deleted*(ignoring memory-full/eviction-policy) from redis-cache.

And there is no relation between the user session and redis server. This two is fully independent. All it depends how and when you are going to delete and store user's session key in redis cache. **If you didn't set any timeout for any key then it will persist as long as it can**.